# SQL Sort by name alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a problem on sorting by alphabet but I want the name with [duplicate] sort at last What I would like to have is at first would sort by alphabet then name with duplicate sort at last. The duplicate might be more than 1.

The result I have done:

```
$sql  = 'SELECT DISTINCT venue_id, name FROM venues ';
$sql .= 'ORDER BY CASE ';
$sql .= 'WHEN name NOT LIKE "%[DUPLICATE]" THEN "1" ';
$sql .= 'WHEN name LIKE "%[DUPLICATE]" THEN "100" ';
$sql .= 'END ASC ';


   *----------*------------------*
    |     ID   |  venue_name     |
    *----------*------------------*
    | 1       | Axxxx            |
    | 2       | Assss            |
    | 5       | Assss [duplicate]| // this is actually the whole name of the venue
    | 6       | Bzzzz            |
    | 7       | Bzzzz [duplicate]|
    | 8       | Fzzzz            |
    | 21      | Fzzzz [duplicate]|
    *----------*-----------------*
```

is it posible for the result be like:

```
*----------*------------------*
|     ID   |  venue_name     |
*----------*------------------*
| 1       | Axxxx            |
| 2       | Assss            |
| 6       | Bzzzz            |
| 8       | Fzzzz            |
| 5       | Assss [duplicate]|
| 7       | Bzzzz [duplicate]|
| 21      | Fzzzz [duplicate]|
*----------*-----------------*
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: @realnumber3012 mysql

Answer (score 1):

hope this could be helpful

```
Set Nocount On

Declare @Table Table
(
     Id             Int
    ,venue_name     Varchar(100)
)

Insert Into @Table(Id,venue_name) Values
 (1,'Axxxx')
,(2,'Assss')
,(5,'Assss')
,(6,'Bzzzz')
,(7,'Bzzzz')
,(8,'Fzzzz')
,(21,'Fzzzz')

;With t1 As
(
    Select   t.Id
            ,t.venue_name
    From    @Table As t
            Join
            (
                Select  Min(t.Id) As Id
                From    @Table As t
                Group By t.venue_name
            ) As t1 On t.Id = t1.Id

    Union All

    Select   t.Id
            ,t.venue_name
    From    @Table As t
            Join 
            (
                Select   Min(t.Id) As Id
                        ,t.venue_name
                From    @Table As t
                Group By t.venue_name
            ) As t2 On t.venue_name = t2.venue_name And t.Id > t2.Id
)

Select  *
From    t1
```

***Edit as per your requirement:-***

```
Insert Into @Table(Id,venue_name) Values
 (1,'Axxxx')
,(2,'Assss')
,(5,'Assss [duplicate]')
,(6,'Bzzzz')
,(7,'Bzzzz [duplicate]')
,(8,'Fzzzz')
,(21,'Fzzzz [duplicate]')

;With t1 As
(
    Select   t.Id
            ,t.venue_name
    From    @Table As t
            Join
            (
                Select  Min(t.Id) As Id
                From    @Table As t
                Group By Replace(t.venue_name,' [duplicate]','')
            ) As t1 On t.Id = t1.Id

    Union All

    Select   t.Id
            ,t.venue_name
    From    @Table As t
            Join 
            (
                Select   Min(t.Id) As Id
                        ,Replace(t.venue_name,' [duplicate]','') As venue_name
                From    @Table As t
                Group By Replace(t.venue_name,' [duplicate]','')
            ) As t2 On Replace(t.venue_name,' [duplicate]','') = t2.venue_name And t.Id > t2.Id
)

Select  *
From    t1
```

Comment: For the duplicate, it is actually the name of the data because i have already set it everytime user enter same venue, it automatically set it as xxxx[duplicate] so now i call it back is with the duplicate word behid the venue name

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this (assuming only one duplicate per entry) is to first select unique records from the list using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

then from there, you can order them however you'd like. The second time around your query would grab everything that remains that was not in the first query. Then you can order that result as well.

Comment: No some of them will maybe have more than 1 duplicate

Comment: Alright. The algorithm still works, but would just need more iterations. Essentially you remove the distinct elements from the list before re-iterating each time. May not be an ideal method.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
WITH t1 (row,id,venue_name)
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY venue_name ORDER BY id ) AS Row
       ,id
      , venue_name
    FROM tablename
    order by venue_name

)
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.
SELECT id,venue_name
FROM t1
order by row
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
id, venue_name , 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t t1 WHERE t.venue_name = t1.venue_name ) - 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t t2 WHERE t.id < t2.id AND t.venue_name = venue_name )  AS num
FROM t
ORDER BY num, name
```

calc row_number() for mySQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t1.id, t1.name from source_table as t1
    left join (select min(id) as id,
                      name
                 from source_table
             group by name) as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
order by 
    case when t2.name is not null then 0 else 1 end,
    name
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aae36/19)

Edit: With your new information (comment), it becomes simpler:

```
SELECT id, name FROM source_table
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN name LIKE '%[duplicate]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    name
```

... and that should be all you need.

Comment: For the [duplicate] I already set it as the name, everytime i create a duplicate venue it will store into databse become Mastiara[Duplicate].

Comment: @DemonLee: in that case it becomes much simpler. See edited answer. However, I don't think it's good practice to add a marker to the name like that. What if one of the 'masters' gets deleted? Or you want to display them differently? Or 'GROUP BY' name? It's always a good idea to store the data as cleanly as possible, and only apply formatting/comments when you query it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check it, if it works for you-

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             (@rn := IF(@v = venue_name, @rn + 1,
                        IF(@v := venue_name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) AS seqnum
      FROM (SELECT venue_name,id FROM venues) s CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @v := '', @rn := 0) params
      ORDER BY venue_name
     ) s
ORDER BY (seqnum = 1) DESC,
         id ASC;
```

Note: I have just changed query as per your requirement but did not check output, so please check and let me know issue if not getting your desired output, so that I can correct if there is any issue.